# .groupby & .fillna with median

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
# Create a groupby object: by_sex_class
by_sex_class = titanic.groupby(["sex","pclass"]).count()

# Write a function that imputes median
def impute_median(series):
    return series.fillna(series.median())

# Impute age and assign to titanic['age']
titanic.age = by_sex_class["age"].transform(impute_median)

# Print the output of titanic.tail(10)
print(titanic.tail(10))
```

I'm unclear how can we assign the column, ["age"] from modified (grouped) df, by_sex_class, to the original (un-grouped) df, titanic.

Wouldn't the assignments be jumbled up?

Thanks in advance for your explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new values are matched to the original dataframe by the **index** (when you group, you still keep the original index).

```
df['age'] = df.groupby(["sex","pclass"])['age'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

Answer (score 5):

I will recommend using this

```
df['age'].fillna(df.groupby(["sex","pclass"])['age'].transform('median'),inplace=True)
```